# Как сделать отступ от определенного элемента

Tags: css

Тестирую простую HTML страничку.

```
<body onload="startApp()">

<header id="menu">
    <a href="#" id="linkHome">Home</a> 
    <a href="#" id="linkLogin">Login</a> 
    <a href="#" id="linkLogout">Logout</a>
    <span id="loggedInUser"></span>
</header>

<section id="loadingBox">Loading ...</section>

<section id="infoBox">Info</section>

<section id="errorBox">Error</section>

<main>
<section id="viewHome">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    Welcome to eShop.
</section>
```

Секции "loadingBox" и т.д всплываюшиеся сообщения об ошибке и т.д. Проблема что когда появляется при помощи jQuery подобная секция, то основная "main" опускается вниз и когда сообщение исчезает, то основная секция поднимается. Как сделать статический отступ от HEADER-a?

Comment: у тех секций которые всплывают должен быть position:absolute;

Comment: у тех секций которые всплывают должен быть position:absolute; top: 0; а у main можно сделать padding-top: 50px; при этом "всплывающие" секции надо перенести сразу под тег main и задать ему (main) position: relative; ...вариантов масса... нужно больше деталей задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите видеть в результате, но...

Как вариант - можете создать контейнер-обертку в который будут выводиться сообщения (какой нибудь messages-wrapper), но будут проблемы, если сообщений несколько и сумма их высот превышает выделенное пространство. В это случае, поможет применение к обертке свойства css min-height со значением равным предполагаемой высоте выделенного пространства:

`min-height: 100px`